# NoedJS forEach with add new element on a http-request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

how to add new element in an array with a http request.

I have a code like this but it doesn't add new element because of async on nodejs and I don't know how can I pass it.

```
   arr =  [
     { id: 123},
     { id: 124},
     { id: 125},
     { id: 126},
    ]
    arr.forEach(function(row, index) {
            request.post('/test')
                    .then((data) => {
                            row.status = "success"
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                            row.status = "failed"
                    });
    });
```

so that i can achieve something like this.

```
[
 { id: 123, status: 'success' },
 { id: 124, status: 'failed' },
 { id: 125, status: 'failed' },
 { id: 126, status: 'success' },
]
```

I'm new in NodeJs. thank you guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Promise.all` because you're handling several promises:

```
let arr =  [
     { id: 123},
     { id: 124},
     { id: 125},
     { id: 126}
]

Promise.all(arr.map((row, index) => {
    return request.post('/test')
        .then(data => {
            row.status = "success"
        })
        .catch(error => {
            row.status = "failed"
        });
})).then(() => console.log(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this popular node module [Async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html). Try this .each here http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each.

```
async.each(arr, _your_function, (err) => {
// check success
})
_your_function(){}
```

Comment: Ah thanks. but how can I access the index? or to add a status element in the arr?

Answer (score 0):

use async.eachOf, you can access element and index in the array.

```
var async = require("async");


var arr =  [
 { id: 123},
 { id: 124},
 { id: 125},
 { id: 126},
];

async.eachOf(arr, function(e, i, ecb){

     request.post('/test',)
    .then( (data) => {
            e.status = "success"
            return ecb(null);
    })
    .catch( (error) => {
            e.status = "failed"
            return ecb(null);
    });


}, function(err){

    if(err)
    {
        console.log("err");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(arr);
    }
});
```